# Writing query for foreign key association

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have 2 tables in database User and Link. The userid is a foreign in the link table. I have used hibernate reverse engg xml to create the model classes in java. 
It has created the User, Link, LinkId class. Here the Link class links the 2 tables, while LinkId contains the attributes of Link.
I am trying to query the link table using the userid. The query I have is "createQuery(
"from com.paypal.socialpay.models.LinkId li where li.userid=?").setInteger(0, id).list();"

But on execution of the query I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No positional parameters in query: from com.paypal.socialpay.models.LinkId li where li.userid=?"

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

```
class name="com.paypal.socialpay.models.Link" table="link" catalog="socialdb">
    <composite-id name="id" class="com.paypal.socialpay.models.LinkId">
        <key-property name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="userid" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="userid" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="title" type="string">
            <column name="title" length="100" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="price" type="string">
            <column name="price" length="100" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="description" length="500" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="contentname" type="string">
            <column name="contentname" length="100" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="contentpreviewname" type="string">
            <column name="contentpreviewname" length="100" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="contentdisplayname" type="string">
            <column name="contentdisplayname" length="100" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="contentpreviewdisplayname" type="string">
            <column name="contentpreviewdisplayname" length="100" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="downloadlink" type="string">
            <column name="downloadlink" length="100" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="contentsavelocation" type="string">
            <column name="contentsavelocation" length="150" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="previewsavelocation" type="string">
            <column name="previewsavelocation" length="150" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="com.paypal.socialpay.models.User" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
session.createQuery("from Link where userid=:userId")
    .setParameter("userId", id)
    .list()
```

UPDATE:  I believe the mapping should look like this:

```
    <id name="id" column="id">
      <generator class="native"/> 
    </id>
    <property name="userid" column="userid"/>
```

etc. with properties, not `<key-property>`s

The query doesn't work because you're trying to select from a LinkId - which is not entity, but a key of Link. Probably some reverse engineering issue.

Comment: On running the query the following exception occurs "org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [userId]"

Comment: @Hozefa Pls provide more source code around your query. Both positional and named params should work.

Comment: What is the object you're calling 'createQuery' from? Can you post your mapping file (*.hbm.xml) or the source file of LinkId with annotations?

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky hbm.xml is added.